# Is there any way to add a Wishlist that is toggled than data is displayed in specified by id as Wishlist area

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Issues**
**It will help with any suggestion, Plz**

- Can we add **each** card in **wishlist area** and **hide or display** when **heart is clicked** - **Duplicate**
- Can it be done using **single Java script** - As there can be many lists

```js
function wishlist(wish) {
  wish.classList.toggle("toggleHeart");
}
```

```css
.toggleHeart {
  background-color: rgb(253, 12, 120);
  color: white;
}

.wishlist {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <span class="wishlist" onclick="wishlist(this)">Heart</span>

  <ul>
    <li>Windows 10</li>
    <li>8GB Ram</li>
    <li>1TB SSD</li>
    <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
    <li>NVIDIA GeForce</li>
    <li>Full HD Display</li>
    <li>Dolby Audio</li>
    <li>1 Warranty</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <span class="wishlist" onclick="wishlist(this)">Heart</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Windows 20</li>
    <li>16GB Ram</li>
    <li>10TB SSD</li>
    <li>Intel Core i15 (21th Gen)</li>
    <li>NVIDIA</li>
    <li>Double HD Display</li>
    <li>Dolby Audio</li>
    <li>2 Warranty</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<div>Wishlist Area</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a unique `data-id` for each `ul` and after that you just append the `ul` to the `wish-list-area`.

```js
const wishListDiv = document.getElementById('wish-list-area');

function wishlist(wish) {
  const ul = wish.nextElementSibling;
  toggleWishList(ul)
  wish.classList.toggle("toggleHeart");
}

function toggleWishList(ul) {
  ul = ul.cloneNode(true)
  const id = ul.dataset.id;
  const existingList = wishListDiv.querySelector(`ul[data-id='${id}']`);
  
  if(existingList) existingList.remove();
  else wishListDiv.appendChild(ul);

 
}
```

```css
.toggleHeart {
  background-color: rgb(253, 12, 120);
  color: white;
}

.wishlist {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  width: 50%
}

#wish-list-area {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <span class="wishlist" onclick="wishlist(this)">Heart</span>

  <ul data-id="1">
    <li>Windows 10</li>
    <li>8GB Ram</li>
    <li>1TB SSD</li>
    <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
    <li>NVIDIA GeForce</li>
    <li>Full HD Display</li>
    <li>Dolby Audio</li>
    <li>1 Warranty</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <span class="wishlist" onclick="wishlist(this)">Heart</span>
  <ul data-id="2">
    <li>Windows 20</li>
    <li>16GB Ram</li>
    <li>10TB SSD</li>
    <li>Intel Core i15 (21th Gen)</li>
    <li>NVIDIA</li>
    <li>Double HD Display</li>
    <li>Dolby Audio</li>
    <li>2 Warranty</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<div id="wish-list-area">Wishlist Area</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother , Also can we specify the name of toggled wishlist like there are 15 lists 5 are toggled and I want to get 3rd toggled one ,is there any way to do that

Comment: @saad In that case you can add your `data-id` dynamically. You can create a new post regarding that issue. Since that requires some extra modification.

Comment: Bro can you tell about this code ` ul = ul.cloneNode(true)
  const id = ul.dataset.id;const existingList = wishListDiv.querySelector(`ul[data-id='${id}']`);`  and `wish.nextElementSibling;`

Comment: `ul = ul.cloneNode(true)` here i'm cloning the original `ul`
`const id = ul.dataset.id;` here i picked the `data-id` from ul
Then i just used `querySelector` to find a `ul` with that `id`